# SSO error in Salesforce1 - Salesforce as IDp

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on

I have set up Salesforce as IDp as well as SP. I am able to login to Service Provider org by navigating to URL of IDp "https://MyDomain.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0sp40000000T3fU" from Browser.

However, When I try to attempt same from Salesforce1, I am geeting error like

> The value of the "app" parameter contains a character that is not
>   allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length.

I already searched everything and found that it has something to do with "RelayState", Not sure how to configure it.

Please suggest some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to resolve above problem, However I got hint from this article "https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth" to try for SP initiated SSO.

So, In MyDOmain setting page of ServiceProvider, I disables standard login page of salesforce and enable SSO settings created previously.

In Salesforce1, I set up URL of Service Provider and it worked. I have documented this in [one of my blog post](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/salesforce/implement-saml-based-single-sign-on-sso-salesforce-as-identity-provider-idp-salesforce-as-service-provider-sp/).

Please share your thoughts on same issue so that it would help me and others to understand it better.

Jitendra Zaa